# Unchecked assignment for 'java.util.ArrayList'

Tags: java, android, arraylist, warnings

I get the warning:

> Unchecked assignment for 'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.ArrayList < com.test.mytest >'

for:

```
private ArrayList<LocoList> myLocations = new ArrayList();
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Yes, you have right. Thanks!

Comment: Simple. Don't use raw types.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want `new ArrayList<>();` so that you use the right generic type. At the moment you're using the raw type on the right hand side of `=`. So you want:

```
private ArrayList<LocoList> myLocations = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or just be explicit:

```
private ArrayList<LocoList> myLocations = new ArrayList<LocoList>();
```

(You might also consider making the type of the variable `List<LocoList>` instead of `ArrayList<LocoList>`, unless you're using `ArrayList`-specific members. I'd also ditch the "my" prefix, personally.)